# Missing or insufficient permissions with AngularFirestore

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, angularfire

I'm getting following error when I try to get doc form Firestore (angular@12.0.3 and angular/fire@6.1.5):

> ERROR FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.

According to firebase's manual, I wrote rules for firestore:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /collection/document {
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
      allow write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the code from my service:

```
constructor(
    private store: AngularFirestore,
    private db: AngularFireDatabase,
    private auth: AuthService
  ) {
    // this.auth.user$ = this.angularFireAuth.user
    this.auth.user$.subscribe(user => {
      if (user && user.email) {
        this.store.doc('/collection/document').valueChanges().subscribe(_ => {
          console.log(_); // throws ERROR FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.
        });

        this.db.list<List>(`lists`, ref => ref.orderByChild('owner').equalTo(user.email))
          .valueChanges([], {idField: 'uuid'})
          .subscribe(_ => {
            console.log(_); // works fine
          })
      }
    });
}
```

I'm a bit familiar with firebase rules, so subscription on rtdb works fine (with production-ready rules). And I can receive data from firestore collection if I change read rules with `allow read: if true;`, but of course I want rules to be more strict. So the problem looks like `request.auth` in rules seems to equal null without adequate reason.

Thanks everyone who can help!

Comment: I guess the user does not correctly logged in firebase. Please share your `AuthService`.

Comment: http://pastie.org/p/0Am4srArAUQygDiu4We4pW
I set up basic authentication by email/password. And also, I have strict rules for rtdb queries, wich contains checking email and uid from request.auth. But same rules in firestore fails with `Missing or insufficient permissions`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the firebase package :
https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2838

I did have the same problems after updating all my packages (angular 12, angular/fire, firebase) It was resolved when i downgraded the fireabase package:

npm i firebase@8.6.1

Comment: OMG, thanks a lot! It really works fine now

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying `match /collection/document` to `match /collection/{document}` in your rule.

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing changed... I tried `match /collection/{document}` and `/{document=**}` - and still get error. And also, I checked my rules in playground - got `Simulated read allowed` with authenticated flag and `Simulated read denied` without it.

Comment: Hmmm, how about modifying `return this.angularFireAuth.user;` to `return this.angularFireAuth.authState;` in `get user$()`.

Comment: Nope, nothing changed again:(
I tried some others ad hoc solutions like setting timeout on firestore request, or making request right after authentication...