# Firestore Security Rules Not Working For a Single Collection

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have the following security rule in firestore.rules, for the explicit purpose of being able to retrieve the emergencycarecontacts by default:

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  
    match /emergencycarecontacts/{contactId} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow create: if true;
      allow update: if true;
      allow delete: if true;
    }
    
  }
}
```

I have the following test in mocha, that says that the read is allowed when I run it:

```js
it("Testing read by theirId succeeds for emergency care contact", async() => {
  // Set Friends not necessary here
  const admin = getAdminFirestore();
  const contactId = "contact1"
  const ecPath = "/emergencycarecontacts/" + contactId;

  const setupECDoc = admin.doc(ecPath);
  await setupECDoc.set({
    modGuardId: theirId,
    type: "physician",
    name: "Dr. Stevens",
    myAddress: "555 San Jose St.",
    myPhone: 5551234567,
  });

  const db = getFirestore(theirAuth);
  const testDoc = db.doc(ecPath);
  await firebase.assertSucceeds(testDoc.get());
});
```

The above test passes when I run `firebase --project=myproject emulators:exec "npm run test"`.

However, when I try to read this live with the following Angular Method:

```js
getModGuardKidsEmergencyCareContactsData() {
    return this.getModGuardKidsEmergencyCareContacts().pipe(
      tap((emergencyCareContacts: string[]) =>
        console.log(
          "This is emergencyCareContacts in getModGuardKidsEmergencyCareContactsData",
          emergencyCareContacts
        )
      ),
      switchMap((emergencyCareContacts: string[]) => {
        let metaDataDocs = emergencyCareContacts.map((ecc) => {
          console.log(
            "This is ecc in MAP getModGuardKidsEmergencyCareContactsData",
            ecc
          );
          return this.afs
            .doc(`emergencycarecontacts/${ecc}`)
            .snapshotChanges()
            .pipe(
              map((doc) => {
                return {
                  ecContactId: doc.payload.id,
                  ...(doc.payload.data() as EmergencyCareContactWithoutId),
                } as EmergencyCareContact;
              }),
              tap((emergencyCareContacts: EmergencyCareContact) =>
                console.log(
                  "This is emergencyCareContacts in TAP getModGuardKidsEmergencyCareContactsData",
                  emergencyCareContacts
                )
              )
            );
        });
        return metaDataDocs.length ? combineLatest(metaDataDocs) : of([]);
      }),
      tap((ecs: EmergencyCareContact[]) =>
        console.log(
          "This is EmergencyCareContact[] in getModGuardKidsEmergencyCareContactsData",
          ecs
        )
      )
    );
  }
```

I get:

```js
This is emergencyCareContacts in getModGuardKidsEmergencyCareContactsData 
Array [ "aYjxiRNBxo8fATiernKp" ]
​
0: "aYjxiRNBxo8fATiernKp"
​
length: 1
​
<prototype>: Array []
kids.service.ts:1048:16
This is ecc in MAP getModGuardKidsEmergencyCareContactsData aYjxiRNBxo8fATiernKp kids.service.ts:1055:18
ERROR FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.
    FirestoreError index.cjs.js:352
    node_modules vendor.js:146169
    node_modules vendor.js:146660
    node_modules vendor.js:142673
    node_modules vendor.js:142602
    node_modules vendor.js:142642
    node_modules vendor.js:133011
    invoke zone.js:391
    run zone.js:150
    scheduleResolveOrReject zone.js:889
    invokeTask zone.js:423
    runTask zone.js:195
    drainMicroTaskQueue zone.js:601
    invokeTask zone.js:502
    invokeTask zone.js:1744
    globalZoneAwareCallback zone.js:1770
    customScheduleGlobal zone.js:1883
    scheduleTask zone.js:410
    scheduleTask zone.js:238
    scheduleEventTask zone.js:264
    makeAddListener zone.js:2054
    set zone.js:1393
    node_modules vendor.js:165693
    cc index.esm.js:23
    dc index.esm.js:22
    node_modules vendor.js:165708
    Ab index.esm.js:21
    invoke zone.js:391
    run zone.js:150
    scheduleResolveOrReject zone.js:889
    invokeTask zone.js:423
    runTask zone.js:195
    drainMicroTaskQueue zone.js:601
    invokeTask zone.js:502
    invokeTask zone.js:1744
    globalZoneAwareCallback zone.js:1770
    customScheduleGlobal zone.js:1883
    scheduleTask zone.js:410
    scheduleTask zone.js:238
    scheduleEventTask zone.js:264
    makeAddListener zone.js:2054
    set zone.js:1393
    node_modules vendor.js:165693
    cc index.esm.js:23
    dc index.esm.js:22
    node_modules vendor.js:165708
    Ab index.esm.js:21
    invoke zone.js:391
    run zone.js:150
    scheduleResolveOrReject zone.js:889
    invokeTask zone.js:423
    runTask zone.js:195
    drainMicroTaskQueue zone.js:601
    invokeTask zone.js:502
    invokeTask zone.js:1744
    globalZoneAwareCallback zone.js:1770
    customScheduleGlobal zone.js:1883
    scheduleTask zone.js:410
    scheduleTask zone.js:238
    scheduleEventTask zone.js:264
    makeAddListener zone.js:2054
    set zone.js:1393
    node_modules vendor.js:165693
    cc index.esm.js:23
    dc index.esm.js:22
    node_modules vendor.js:165708
    Ab index.esm.js:21
    invoke zone.js:391
    run zone.js:150
    scheduleResolveOrReject zone.js:889
    invokeTask zone.js:423
    runTask zone.js:195
    drainMicroTaskQueue zone.js:601
    invokeTask zone.js:502
    invokeTask zone.js:1744
    globalZoneAwareCallback zone.js:1770
    customScheduleGlobal zone.js:1883
    scheduleTask zone.js:410
    scheduleTask zone.js:238
    scheduleEventTask zone.js:264
    makeAddListener zone.js:2054
    set zone.js:1393
    node_modules vendor.js:165693
    cc index.esm.js:23
    dc index.esm.js:22
    node_modules vendor.js:165708
core.js:15724
```

It is complaining I cannot read: aYjxiRNBxo8fATiernKp, which is ridiculous as it exists in the db as I have verified. I have also verified that when deploying these rules, the deployment was reflected in the rules as seen online in the firebase console. This is the only match block that is not working as I have 100+ other tests that are passing, along with the actual local test for emergencycarecontacts passing.

Is there any way to force reset the rules for firestore?

This is just a small segment of the many firestore rules that I have, as well as small part of my overall code. I am simply trying to force the rules for a read and that does not even work. Please let me know any strategies for resetting the rules and I would be most grateful.
​

Comment: Hi @Willem Ghijsen , "Is there any way to force reset the rules for firestore?" - Have you already checked you're active Firestore Rules? Go to your Firebase Console > Firestore Database > Click on the rules tab. Also see, [Firestore Security Rules Playground](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/simulator#use_the).

Comment: Hi Marc, I have checked the active rules and confirmed that I have:

match /emergencycarecontacts/{contactId} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow create: if true;
      allow update: if true;
      allow delete: if true;
    }

for my emergencycarecontacts security rules live in the console.

Comment: It gets stranger.. after using the console Rules Playground I sent a get request to /emergencycarecontacts/aYjxiRNBxo8fATiernKp and it worked saying, "simulated read allowed". However, when I run my code again against the live database, I get the same Firestore error as above.

Comment: After looking over code upstream of the observable that was reading the emergencycarecontact there was a problem reading in another collection called offlinecontact, and the problem was happening there. What is confusing to me is why the error was thrown where it was and not upstream in the observable that had bad data.

Comment: Are you using `AngularFire`? Could you please check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67872156/missing-or-insufficient-permissions-with-angularfirestore) and see if helps?